# Как запустить обратный отсчет корректно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

Имеется счетчик обратного отсчета на countdown.js, который обнуляется каждые 24 часа. Его цель - показывать, сколько осталось до конца суток на текущий момент времени в секундах, минутах и часах.
Как сделать, чтобы он при разработке он  имел сессию общую для всех пользователей, не запускался заново при обновлении страницы и сразу показывал корректное время до конца дня?

```js
var fiveSeconds = () => new Date().getTime() + 86400100;

$('#clock').countdown(fiveSeconds(), {
  elapse: true
}).on('update.countdown', function(e) {
  if (e.elapsed) {
    $(this).countdown(fiveSeconds());
  } else {
    $(this).html(e.strftime('<div class="time-wrap"><div class="once">%H</div><div class="once">ЧАСЫ</div></div><div class="time-wrap"><div class="once">%M</div><div class="once">МИНУТЫ</div></div><div class="time-wrap"><div class="once">%S</div><div class="once">СЕКУНДЫ</div></div>'));
  }
});
```

```css
#clock {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #e30b18;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 51px;
    padding: 11px 11px 11px 11px;
    background: #ffffffd1;
}
#clock *{
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/master/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: А если просто читать время при запуске (сервера, например) и отсчет вести от него?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. До конца суток - где? Если в браузере, то какое значение может иметь обновление страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если без countdown.js

```js
function countdownDay() {
 let now = new Date(),
   hLeft = 23 - now.getHours(),
   mLeft = 59 - now.getMinutes(),
   sLeft = 59 - now.getSeconds(),
    $timeeWrappers = $('.time-wrap');

 mLeft = mLeft > 10 ? mLeft : "0" + mLeft;
 sLeft = sLeft > 10 ? sLeft : "0" + sLeft;

  $timeeWrappers.eq(0).children('.once').text(hLeft);
  $timeeWrappers.eq(1).children('.once').text(mLeft);
  $timeeWrappers.eq(2).children('.once').text(sLeft);
}

countdownDay();
setInterval(countdownDay, 1000);
```

```css
#clock {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #e30b18;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 51px;
    padding: 11px 11px 11px 11px;
    background: #ffffffd1;
}
#clock *{
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock">
  <div class="time-wrap">
    <div class="once">q</div>
      <div class="once-b">ЧАСЫ</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-wrap">
      <div class="once">w</div>
      <div class="once-b">МИНУТЫ</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-wrap">
    <div class="once">e</div>
    <div class="once-b">СЕКУНДЫ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```